# Intel MPI - mpiexec.exe does not run, only gives a blank screen

Tags: windows, fortran, mpi, mpiexec, intel-mpi

I have some problem running mpiexec.exe on my computer. I installed intel parallel studio xe cluster edition on my windows 10 laptop, which includes intel-mpi. Then I registered my mpi following this page:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-mpi-for-windows

and then I configured my visual studio 2013 according  to:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/610381

However, when I compile and run the MPI program (in Fortran), a cmd window pops up but nothing shows up. The I tried to use

```
  mpiexec.exe -n 4 myprogram.exe
```

directly in a cmd window as administrator, nothing shows up after the execution command. I checked my task manager that my program is not running and the entire window just stays like that forever until I hit Ctrl+C to terminate it.

The same program runs perfectly on my desktop and I configured my desktop using exact the same way. I am really confused about this issue since it does not give any error message but a blank screen. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: What does your program do when run in serial? What kind of output do you expect? Does your code work anywhere else? If not, we have to see tue code.

Comment: Hi Vladirmir,  It has the same problem with all the fortran codes I write. For example, I tried a program that only writes "hello world" on the screen and it runs perfectly when it running in serial. But if I use mpiexec.exe to run it, it just gives nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a known bug in the Intel MPI runtime for x64 (only) that was provided by Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 Update 1. There is this item buried in the PSXE release notes:

> Intel® MPI Library 2017 Update 1 may hang at initialization on a
>   Windows* platform. If this occurs, either set
>   I_MPI_COLL_INTRANODE=pt2pt or run with administrative privileges to
>   work around the hang.

Replacing the x64 libimpimd.dll with the one from 17.0.0 also works. My understanding is that this will be fixed in Update 2.

Comment: Hi Steve, I tried to run it with administrative privilege and it does not work. Can you please tell me where I can find the x64 libimpimd.dll  file? Thank you!

Comment: Also, I tried to open cmd with administrator's privilege and ran set I_MPI_COLL_INTRANODE=pt2pt, but the problem still persists.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, it's impimt.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\mpirt  The two other solutions work when I try them, though it's of course possible your problem is something else.   If you compile a source with only an END statement for Intel 64 with /Qcoarray , will it run? What happens when you press ^C on your program?

Comment: Hi Steve thank you for your reply. I copied   impimt.dll from "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.0.109\windows\mpi\intel64\bin" to  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\mpirt" as you suggested, but the problem persists. Please let me know if I did not do it correctly. I also tried to compile a file with only an END statement in it for intel 64 with /Qcoarray. It compiles and runs (in serial) normally. But I run it with mpiexec.exe, it just gives m a blank screen forever. If I press ^C, it just stops and nothing happens.

Comment: Hi Steve, I just checked my friend's laptop and he has the same issue. Both of us use the same Parallel Studio XE 2017 Cluster Edition and we both use Lenovo laptops. Is it possible that the intel MPI conflicts with any software installed on Lenovo laptops? Sorry for the silly question and I am very new to Intel MPI.

Comment: If when compiled with /Qcoarray it runs directly (that isn't serial), then you have a different issue. I suggest you post in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-clusters-and-hpc-technology and ask for help. One last thing to try - copy the 17.0.0.109 DLL into the same folder as the EXE and see what happens.

Comment: Hi Steve, I already posted the same post on that forum and someone is looking at my output files.  I am not sure what does your last sentence mean. Do I copy all the DLL files in "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.0.109\window‌​s\mpi\intel64\bin" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\mpirt" ?

Comment: I meant just copy impirt.dll